# Perushim on the TA"Z

Tags: halacha, commentaries

I'm aware that generally speaking the Machatzis Hashekel as well as the Ashel Avraham (Pri Migadim) act as perushim on the Magen Avraham. In fact, the Pri migadim has a perush on the TA"Z called Meshbetzos Zahav. However, I'm looking for a perush on a The TA"Z that's similar to the perush Machatzis Hashekel on the Magen Avraham. Any suggestions?

Comment: To help answerers give you what you're looking for, could you explain what it is about Machatzis Hashekel you like and are looking for?

Comment: Those who know know

Comment: @Moshe but the whole point of this site is that it is not only for those who know - but also for those who don't know and want to know

Comment: My experience with the Taz vs Magen Avraham is the latter is often much more terse, requiring three commentaries on it (the two you mention and levushei serad). The Taz in contrast is much more explicit. Not always, but enough that there wasn't as much of a need for a commentary. That being said the levushei serad also explains the Taz, but not to the same depth as the two you mention.

Comment: @Moshe There are many. But first you must tell us which part of orach chaim you are learning. Not everyone is on everything.

Comment: Hilchos Tzitzis @interested